# g++ Unicode variable name

Tags: unicode, variables, g++

I am trying to use Unicode variable names in g++, but it does not appear to work.

Does g++ not support Unicode variable names? Or is there some subset of Unicode (from which I'm not testing in)?

Comment: ¤ g++ is just not standard-conforming wrt. characters in identifiers. But I don't know of any compiler that *is* conforming. It is my impression that most compilers limit the identifier characters to English A...Z and underscore, plus $ sign, which is wrong in two ways: not allowing the huge range of Unicode characters specified in Annex E of the standard (I've listed them at http://pastie.org/3110152), and allowing $, which the standard does not allow. In short, the standard and existing practice is very much at odds. Perhaps with C++11... ;-) Cheers & hth.,

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Try clang :)

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[ (and other Unicode characters) in identifiers not allowed by g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692067/)*.

Comment: "it does not appear to work" Don't hesitate, go ahead and tell us *how* it doesn't work. We've been waiting for 13 years.

Comment: @n. m. could be an AI: The OP has left the building: *"Last seen more than 12 years ago"*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to specify the [`-fextended-identifiers`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-fextended-identifiers) flag when compiling. You also have to use \uXXXX or \uXXXXXXXX for Unicode (at least in GCC, it's Unicode).

Identifiers (variable/class names, etc.) in g++ can't be of UTF-8/UTF-16 or whatever encoding. They have to be:

```
identifier:
  nondigit
  identifier nondigit
  identifier digit
```

A nondigit is

```
nondigit: one of
  universalcharactername
  _ a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
  A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
```

And a universalcharactername is

```
universalcharactername:
  \UXXXXXXXX
  \uXXXX
```

Thus, if you save your source file as UTF-8, you cannot have a variable like:

```cpp
int høyde = 10;
```

It had to be written like:

```cpp
int h\u00F8yde = 10;
```

(which, in my opinion, would defeat the purpose. So just stick with a-z)

Comment: Is there better support in clang?

Comment: I don't know, but you should ask another question for that.

Comment: g++ is not standard-conforming here (but neither are other compilers, including Comeau). For standard C++, in the very first phase of translation "Any source file character not in the basic source character set (2.3) is replaced by the universal-character-name that designates that character", and the lexer rules operate on the result of that. In the C++11 standard this is specified in "Phases of translation" §2.2/1 1st list item.

Comment: @anon Yes, clang allows accented characters in identifiers.

Comment: @anon **yes**, from clang 3.3 onwards [there is](http://llvm.org/releases/3.3/tools/clang/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#extended-identifiers-unicode-support-and-universal-character-names) support for unicode identifiers right in UTF-8.

Comment: 9 years later G++ 9.1 is _still_ blind to UTF-8 symbols, even with `-fextended-identifiers -finput-charset=UTF-8`. (For reference, also MSVC++ does fine, either with -utf-8 or with a BOM in the source.) See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12693346/1479945

Answer (score 5):

A one-line patch to the C++ preprocessor allows UTF-8 input.  Details for GCC are given at *[UTF-8 Identifiers in GCC](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=802657)*.

However, since the preprocessor is shared, the same patch should work for g++ as well.  In particular, the patch needed, as of gcc-5.2 is

```
diff -cNr gcc-5.2.0/libcpp/charset.c gcc-5.2.0-ejo/libcpp/charset.c
```

Output:

```
*** gcc-5.2.0/libcpp/charset.c  Mon Jan  5 04:33:28 2015
--- gcc-5.2.0-ejo/libcpp/charset.c  Wed Aug 12 14:34:23 2015
***************
*** 1711,1717 ****
    struct _cpp_strbuf to;
    unsigned char *buffer;

!   input_cset = init_iconv_desc (pfile, SOURCE_CHARSET, input_charset);
    if (input_cset.func == convert_no_conversion)
      {
        to.text = input;
--- 1711,1717 ----
    struct _cpp_strbuf to;
    unsigned char *buffer;

!   input_cset = init_iconv_desc (pfile, "C99", input_charset);
    if (input_cset.func == convert_no_conversion)
      {
        to.text = input;
```

Note that for the above patch to work, a recent version of [iconv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv) needs to be installed that supports [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) conversions.  Type `iconv --list` to verify this. Otherwise, you can install a new version of iconv along with GCC as described in the link above.

Change the configure command to

```
../gcc-5.2.0/configure -v --disable-multilib \
    --with-libiconv-prefix=/usr/local/gcc-5.2 \
    --prefix=/usr/local/gcc-5.2 \
    --enable-languages="c,c++"
```

if you are building for x86 and want to include the C++ compiler as well.