# Saving files as UTF-8 when programming in C

Tags: c, character-encoding

This might be a simple question, but I want to make sure.

I want some comments in my .c files to use symbols not supported in the default encoding. If I save the file as UTF-8 for instance, and I only use symbols in comments, is there any way this can affect the compiler in any way?

Need to be sure of this.

Comment: Captain obvious is obvious: you cannot use UTF-8 characters in function or variable names (or `char`s). As long as you only use them in strings and comments, you are fine.

Comment: @Tim: It depends on C mode and compiler version -- see [Is it possible to get GCC to compile UTF-8 with BOM source files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899795/is-it-possible-to-get-gcc-to-compile-utf-8-with-bom-source-files) and comments therein.

Comment: Oops -- seems this is still in the experimental phase with gcc. It works but requires you to enter extended characters as '\uXXXX', which kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: @Jongware: I was only asking about special characters/ UTF-8 in comments not in code, but I value your input and it was interesting reading.

Comment: At least it shows "the" C standard (1978) is still under active development. I love the built-in UTF8 support in what's rapidly becoming my *second* preferred programming language: Javascript. There is something very satisfying about having a line `π=2;`.

Comment: Satisfying? Seems horrifying to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the preprocessor will strip all of that out anyway.