# How can I convert Unicode C source code for GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, unicode

I inherited a pretty large C code base that uses Unicode identifiers widely (UTF-8 encoded).

I have to build it with GCC (any version is fine, but I can't recompile it), and I get a lot of `error: stray ‘\302’ in program` (763 of these errors).

I cannot simply remove all the Unicode characters because of name collisions.
I cannot use `iconv` because a certain amount of characters get translated to `?` that is not valid inside an identifiers (and obviously I cannot replace all `?` to a different character because the code base also use ternary operator widely).

Is there a better way than manually edit every single Unicode character?
The best solution would be automatic and reversible (just in case GCC finally start supporting Unicode properly).

**Note**: I'm aware of the current [GCC limitations and of the patch provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899795/is-it-possible-to-get-gcc-to-compile-utf-8-with-bom-source-files), but I cannot rebuild GCC. Moreover what I'm asking for is an automated way to replace all Unicode characters at once (in a revertible way, if possible), not a way to preserve them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899795/is-it-possible-to-get-gcc-to-compile-utf-8-with-bom-source-files

Comment: unicode identifiers: just don't do it!

Comment: @nneonneo this is not a duplicate: I'm aware of the current GCC limitations and of the patch provided, but I cannot rebuild gcc. Moreover what I'm asking for is an automated way to replace all unicode characters at once (in a revertible way, if possible), not a way to preserve them, like the other question you pointed out.

Comment: If you convert your identifiers to UCN, as in the accepted answer there, and use `-fextended-identifiers`, then you will be able to compile your code without any risk of name clashes, and without having to recompile GCC. Does that not work for you?

Comment: @nneonneo I feel a bit dumb, but if I have to manually change each identifier to UCN, I can adopt a more readable convention, instead. Indeed I do not know any `sed`, `iconv` or `vim` script that can **automate** the conversion to UCN (or to anything else). Am I missing something so obvious that does not deserve an answer?

Comment: The answer at the duplicate question gives a script which uses `perl` to perform the conversion automatically.

Comment: [GCC caught up in version 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692067/and-other-unicode-characters-in-identifiers-not-allowed-by-g/42158646#42158646) (mid 2020).