#  (and other Unicode characters) in identifiers not allowed by g++

Tags: c++, gcc, unicode, c++11, g++

I am  to find that I cannot use  as a valid identifier with g++ 4.7, even with the `-fextended-identifiers` option enabled:

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
  const char*  = "I'm very happy";
  return 0;
}
```

> main.cpp:3:3: error: stray ‘\360’ in program 
> main.cpp:3:3: error: stray ‘\237’ in program 
> main.cpp:3:3: error: stray ‘\230’ in program 
> main.cpp:3:3: error: stray ‘\203’ in program

After some googling, I discovered that [UTF-8 characters are not yet supported in identifiers](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FAQ#What_is_the_status_of_adding_the_UTF-8_support_for_identifier_names_in_GCC.3F), but a *universal-character-name* should work. So I convert my source to:

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
  const char* \U0001F603 = "I'm very happy";
  return 0;
}
```

> main.cpp:3:15: error: universal character \U0001F603 is not valid in an identifier

So apparently  isn't a valid identifier character. However, the standard specifically allows characters from the range `10000-1FFFD` in Annex E.1 and doesn't disallow it as an initial character in E.2.

My next effort was to see if any other allowed Unicode characters worked - but none that I tried did. Not even the ever important [PILE OF POO ()](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f4a9/index.htm) character.

So, for the sake of meaningful and descriptive variable names, what gives? Does `-fextended-identifiers` do as it advertises or not? Is it only supported in the very latest build? And what kind of support do other compilers have?

Comment: Read [this](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/22-keywords-and-naming-identifiers/).

Comment: @ErikEsTT Unfortunately that page doesn't mention that an identifier can contain a `universal-character-name`, so whatever advice they give on naming conventions doesn't take into account the importance of using smiley faces as variable names. See §2.11 of ISO/IEC 14882:2011(E).

Comment: Hmm it seems the program `static const char* x = "I'm very happy";` crashes clang 3.1...

Comment: See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53y7f3az) example.

Comment: `clang` supports this since `3.3` with no special options but `gcc 4.8.1` still doesn't.  Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26660180/unicode-special-characters-in-variable-names-in-clang-not-allowed

Comment: You can, but you need C++11 also your source should be encoded as unicode.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As of 4.8, [GCC does not support characters outside of the BMP used as identifiers](http://repo.or.cz/w/official-gcc.git/blob/5b9a8c31af0e7d0f743e8ba07a3bbe03042f5869:/libcpp/charset.c#l869). It seems to be an unnecessary restriction. Also, GCC only supports a very restricted set of character described in [ucnid.tab](http://repo.or.cz/w/official-gcc.git/blob/5b9a8c31af0e7d0f743e8ba07a3bbe03042f5869:/libcpp/ucnid.tab), based on C**99** and C++**98** (it is not updated to C11 and C++11 yet, it seems).

As described in the manual, [`-fextended-identifiers` is experimental](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html), so it has a higher chance won't work as expected.

---

GCC supported the C11 character set [starting from 4.9.0](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/changes.html#c-family) ([SVN r204886](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc?view=revision&revision=204886) to be precise). So OP's second piece of code using `\U0001F603` does work. I still can't get the actual code using  to work even with `-finput-charset=UTF-8` with GCC 8.2 on https://gcc.godbolt.org though (You may want to follow [this bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67224), provided by [@DanielWolf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42158646/224671)).

Meanwhile, both pieces of code work on Clang 3.3 without any options other than `-std=c++11`.

Comment: How about `main.cpp:3:15: error: universal character \u00a8 is not valid in an identifier`? This is with 4.7, though.

Comment: It [caught up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30130806/using-emoji-as-identifier-names-in-c-in-visual-studio-or-gcc/64108334#64108334) with GCC 10 (2020-05-07). This could be updated (but *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today)

Answer (score 17):

This was a [known bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67224) in GCC 9 and before. This [has been fixed](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67224#c32) in GCC 10.

The [official changelog](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/changes.html#c-family) for GCC 10 contains this section:

> Extended characters in identifiers may now be specified directly in the input encoding (UTF-8, by default), in addition to the UCN syntax (`\uNNNN` or `\UNNNNNNNN`) that is already supported:

```
static const int π = 3;
int get_naïve_pi() {
  return π;
}
```

Comment: There isn't a GCC 10 (10.0), [only GCC 10.1](https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html)(?).

Comment: @PeterMortensen I'm assuming that GCC follows some form of SemVer, so a statement about features in GCC 10 should hold for any 10.x version.

Answer (score 6):

> However, the standard specifically allows characters from the range 10000-1FFFD in Annex E.1 and doesn't disallow it as an initial character in E.2.

One thing to keep in mind is that just because the C++ standard allows (or disallows) some feature, does not necessarily mean that your compiler supports (or doesn't support) that feature.

Comment: Yes, allowing the full set of Unicode characters specified by the standard is one that that, as far as I know, no compilers support yet, either literally or with UCNs.

Comment: Of course! I only meant to find some documentation or source that shows they don't support this feature.

Comment: @sftrabbit Okay, maybe my answer is pointing out the obvious. KennyTM gave the link re: gcc.