# Are Unicode and special characters in variable names in Clang not allowed?

Tags: c++, gcc, unicode, clang

Clang now (>3.3) supports Unicode characters in *variable names*: *[Clang 3.3 Release Notes, Major New Features](https://releases.llvm.org/3.3/tools/clang/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#major-new-features)*.

However, some special character are still forbidden.

```
int main(){
    double α = 2.; // Alpha, ok!
    double ∞ = 99999.; // Infinity, error
}
```

giving:

```
error: non-ASCII characters are not allowed outside of literals and identifiers
        double ∞ = 99999.;
```

What is the **fundamental** difference between `α` (alpha) and `∞` (infinity) for Clang? That the former is Unicode and the latter is not Unicode, but at the same time is not ASCII?

Is there a workaround or an option to allow this set of characters in Clang (or BTW in GCC)?

*Notes*: 1) `∞` is just an example; there are a lot of characters that are potentially useful, but also forbidden, like `∫` or `∂`. 2) I am not asking if it is good idea, and please take it as a technical question. 3) I am interested in C++ compiler of Clang 3.4 in Linux ([GCC 4.8.3](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/) (2014-05-22) doesn't support this). I am saving the source files with [gedit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gedit) using [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding and Unix/Linux line ending. 4) adding other normal first characters doesn't help: `_∞`

---

> The answers point to a definite NO. Some ranges are indeed not
> allowed nor will they be soon. To move one step further to total
> craziness, the best alternative I found was to use
> characters that effectively look the same. (Now, *this* I might admit is not a good idea.) Those alternatives can be found here
> http://shapecatcher.com/. The result (sorry if it hurts your eyes):
>
> ```
> //double ∞ = 99999.; // Still an error
> //double ⧞ = 99999.; // Infinity negated. Still an error
>
> double ꝏ = 99999.;   // Letter oo
> double Ꝏ = 99999.;  // Letter OO
>
> //double ⧜ = 99999.; // Incomplete infinity. Still an error
> ```
>
> Other "alternative" dead ringers mentioned in the question that are in the allowed range: `ʃ`, .

<sub>Note: This question has Unicode text that may not display correctly in all browsers.</sub>

Comment: these names are a terrible idea. What do you want to achieve with that? Some sort of obfuscation contest??

Comment: @stefan: Presumably, writing code that looks like mathematical notation. That's not a bad idea if the intended audience is mathematicians.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I'm a mathematician, and I hate it ;-) But fair enough.. It's non-portable though. That's the biggest drawback of anything.

Comment: @stefan I don't think `double const π = 3.14159265359;` is obfuscation used in the right context. Non-portability is another issue and it is part of the answer, after all the standard seems to allow it in a limited way.

Comment: [GCC caught up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30130806/using-emoji-as-identifier-names-in-c-in-visual-studio-or-gcc/64108334#64108334) with [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html) (2020-05-07).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So the Clang document says (*emphasis mine*):

> This feature allows identifiers to contain certain Unicode characters,
> **as specified by the active language standard**;

This is covered in the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) *Annex E*. The characters allowed are as follows:

> E.1 Ranges of characters allowed [charname.allowed]
>
> 00A8, 00AA, 00AD,
>
> 00AF, 00B2-00B5, 00B7-00BA, 00BC-00BE, 00C0-00D6, 00D8-00F6, 00F8-00FF
>
> 0100-167F, 1681-180D, 180F-1FFF 200B-200D, 202A-202E, 203F-2040, 2054,
>
> 2060-206F 2070-218F, 2460-24FF, 2776-2793, 2C00-2DFF, 2E80-2FFF
>
> 3004-3007, 3021-302F, 3031-303F
>
> 3040-D7FF F900-FD3D, FD40-FDCF,
>
> FDF0-FE44, FE47-FFFD
>
> 10000-1FFFD, 20000-2FFFD, 30000-3FFFD,
> 40000-4FFFD, 50000-5FFFD, 60000-6FFFD, 70000-7FFFD, 80000-8FFFD,
> 90000-9FFFD, A0000-AFFFD, B0000-BFFFD, C0000-CFFFD, D0000-DFFFD,
> E0000-EFFFD

The code for infinity `221E` is not included in the list.

*For reference*: these are the codes above converted to Unicode characters (some of them may not display correctly in all browsers/available fonts).

```
¨, ª, ­,

¯, ²-µ, ·-º, ¼-¾, À-Ö, Ø-ö, ø-ÿ

Ā-ᙿ, ᚁ-᠍, ᠏-῿ ​-‍, ‪-‮, ‿-⁀, ⁔,

⁠-⁯ ⁰-↏, ①-⓿, ❶-➓, Ⰰ-ⷿ, ⺀-⿿

〄-〇, 〡-〯, 〱-〿

぀-퟿ 豈-ﴽ, ﵀-﷏,

ﷰ-﹄, ﹇-�

-, -, -, -, -, -, -, -, -, -, -, -, -, -
```

I could not find an extensive document that covers the rationale for the ranges chosen, although [N3146: Recommendations for extended identifier characters for C and C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3146.html) does provide some details on the influences.

---

EDIT 1 (2023):

These are the first 120 characters in each of the groups listed, generated by [a program](https://godbolt.org/z/j9dh4a9zW).
Honestly, it's not a very exciting character set, with no math symbols or APL symbols; it's close to useless, perhaps on purpose.

```
¨ª­|
¯|
²³´µ|
·¸¹º|
¼½¾|
ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ|
ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö|
øùúûüýþÿ|
ĀāĂăĄąĆćĈĉĊċČčĎďĐđĒēĔĕĖėĘęĚěĜĝĞğĠġĢģĤĥĦħĨĩĪīĬĭĮįİıĲĳĴĵĶķĸĹĺĻļĽľĿŀŁłŃńŅņŇňŉŊŋŌōŎŏŐőŒœŔŕŖŗŘřŚśŜŝŞşŠšŢţŤťŦŧŨũŪūŬŭŮůŰűŲųŴŵŶ...|
ᚁᚂᚃᚄᚅᚆᚇᚈᚉᚊᚋᚌᚍᚎᚏᚐᚑᚒᚓᚔᚕᚖᚗᚘᚙᚚ᚛᚜᚝᚞᚟ᚠᚡᚢᚣᚤᚥᚦᚧᚨᚩᚪᚫᚬᚭᚮᚯᚰᚱᚲᚳᚴᚵᚶᚷᚸᚹᚺᚻᚼᚽᚾᚿᛀᛁᛂᛃᛄᛅᛆᛇᛈᛉᛊᛋᛌᛍᛎᛏᛐᛑᛒᛓᛔᛕᛖᛗᛘᛙᛚᛛᛜᛝᛞᛟᛠᛡᛢᛣᛤᛥᛦᛧᛨᛩᛪ᛫᛬᛭ᛮᛯᛰᛱᛲᛳᛴᛵᛶᛷ...|
᠏᠐᠑᠒᠓᠔᠕᠖᠗᠘᠙᠚᠛᠜᠝᠞᠟ᠠᠡᠢᠣᠤᠥᠦᠧᠨᠩᠪᠫᠬᠭᠮᠯᠰᠱᠲᠳᠴᠵᠶᠷᠸᠹᠺᠻᠼᠽᠾᠿᡀᡁᡂᡃᡄᡅᡆᡇᡈᡉᡊᡋᡌᡍᡎᡏᡐᡑᡒᡓᡔᡕᡖᡗᡘᡙᡚᡛᡜᡝᡞᡟᡠᡡᡢᡣᡤᡥᡦᡧᡨᡩᡪᡫᡬᡭᡮᡯᡰᡱᡲᡳᡴᡵᡶᡷᡸ᡹᡺᡻᡼᡽᡾᡿ᢀᢁᢂᢃᢄᢅ...|
​‌‍|
‪‫‬‭‮|
‿⁀|
⁔|
⁠⁡⁢⁣⁤⁥⁦⁧⁨⁩⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯|
⁰ⁱ⁲⁳⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁺⁻⁼⁽⁾ⁿ₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉₊₋₌₍₎₏ₐₑₒₓₔₕₖₗₘₙₚₛₜ₝₞₟₠₡₢₣₤₥₦₧₨₩₪₫€₭₮₯₰₱₲₳₴₵₶₷₸₹₺₻₼₽₾₿⃀⃁⃂⃃⃄⃅⃆⃇⃈⃉⃊⃋⃌⃍⃎⃏⃒⃓⃘⃙⃚⃐⃑⃔⃕⃖⃗⃛⃜⃝⃞⃟⃠⃡⃢⃣⃤⃥⃦...|
①②③④⑤⑥⑦⑧⑨⑩⑪⑫⑬⑭⑮⑯⑰⑱⑲⑳⑴⑵⑶⑷⑸⑹⑺⑻⑼⑽⑾⑿⒀⒁⒂⒃⒄⒅⒆⒇⒈⒉⒊⒋⒌⒍⒎⒏⒐⒑⒒⒓⒔⒕⒖⒗⒘⒙⒚⒛⒜⒝⒞⒟⒠⒡⒢⒣⒤⒥⒦⒧⒨⒩⒪⒫⒬⒭⒮⒯⒰⒱⒲⒳⒴⒵ⒶⒷⒸⒹⒺⒻⒼⒽⒾⒿⓀⓁⓂⓃⓄⓅⓆⓇⓈⓉⓊⓋⓌⓍⓎⓏⓐⓑⓒⓓⓔⓕⓖ...|
❶❷❸❹❺❻❼❽❾❿➀➁➂➃➄➅➆➇➈➉➊➋➌➍➎➏➐➑➒➓|
ⰀⰁⰂⰃⰄⰅⰆⰇⰈⰉⰊⰋⰌⰍⰎⰏⰐⰑⰒⰓⰔⰕⰖⰗⰘⰙⰚⰛⰜⰝⰞⰟⰠⰡⰢⰣⰤⰥⰦⰧⰨⰩⰪⰫⰬⰭⰮⰯⰰⰱⰲⰳⰴⰵⰶⰷⰸⰹⰺⰻⰼⰽⰾⰿⱀⱁⱂⱃⱄⱅⱆⱇⱈⱉⱊⱋⱌⱍⱎⱏⱐⱑⱒⱓⱔⱕⱖⱗⱘⱙⱚⱛⱜⱝⱞⱟⱠⱡⱢⱣⱤⱥⱦⱧⱨⱩⱪⱫⱬⱭⱮⱯⱰⱱⱲⱳⱴⱵⱶ...|
⺀⺁⺂⺃⺄⺅⺆⺇⺈⺉⺊⺋⺌⺍⺎⺏⺐⺑⺒⺓⺔⺕⺖⺗⺘⺙⺚⺛⺜⺝⺞⺟⺠⺡⺢⺣⺤⺥⺦⺧⺨⺩⺪⺫⺬⺭⺮⺯⺰⺱⺲⺳⺴⺵⺶⺷⺸⺹⺺⺻⺼⺽⺾⺿⻀⻁⻂⻃⻄⻅⻆⻇⻈⻉⻊⻋⻌⻍⻎⻏⻐⻑⻒⻓⻔⻕⻖⻗⻘⻙⻚⻛⻜⻝⻞⻟⻠⻡⻢⻣⻤⻥⻦⻧⻨⻩⻪⻫⻬⻭⻮⻯⻰⻱⻲⻳⻴⻵⻶...|
〄々〆〇|
〡〢〣〤〥〦〧〨〩〪〭〮〯〫〬|
〱〲〳〴〵〶〷〸〹〺〻〼〽〾〿|
぀ぁあぃいぅうぇえぉおかがきぎくぐけげこごさざしじすずせぜそぞただちぢっつづてでとどなにぬねのはばぱひびぴふぶぷへべぺほぼぽまみむめもゃやゅゆょよらりるれろゎわゐゑをんゔゕゖ゗゘゙゚゛゜ゝゞゟ゠ァアィイゥウェエォオカガキギクグケゲコゴサザ...|
豈更車賈滑串句龜龜契金喇奈懶癩羅蘿螺裸邏樂洛烙珞落酪駱亂卵欄爛蘭鸞嵐濫藍襤拉臘蠟廊朗浪狼郎來冷勞擄櫓爐盧老蘆虜路露魯鷺碌祿綠菉錄鹿論壟弄籠聾牢磊賂雷壘屢樓淚漏累縷陋勒肋凜凌稜綾菱陵讀拏樂諾丹寧怒率異北磻便復不泌數索參塞省葉說殺辰沈拾若掠略...|
﵀﵁﵂﵃﵄﵅﵆﵇﵈﵉﵊﵋﵌﵍﵎﵏ﵐﵑﵒﵓﵔﵕﵖﵗﵘﵙﵚﵛﵜﵝﵞﵟﵠﵡﵢﵣﵤﵥﵦﵧﵨﵩﵪﵫﵬﵭﵮﵯﵰﵱﵲﵳﵴﵵﵶﵷﵸﵹﵺﵻﵼﵽﵾﵿﶀﶁﶂﶃﶄﶅﶆﶇﶈﶉﶊﶋﶌﶍﶎﶏ﶐﶑ﶒﶓﶔﶕﶖﶗﶘﶙﶚﶛﶜﶝﶞﶟﶠﶡﶢﶣﶤﶥﶦﶧﶨﶩﶪﶫﶬﶭﶮﶯﶰﶱﶲﶳﶴﶵﶶ...|
ﷰﷱﷲﷳﷴﷵﷶﷷﷸﷹﷺﷻ﷼﷽﷾﷿︀︁︂︃︄︅︆︇︈︉︊︋︌︍︎️︐︑︒︓︔︕︖︗︘︙︚︛︜︝︞︟︧︨︩︪︫︬︭︠︡︢︣︤︥︦︮︯︰︱︲︳︴︵︶︷︸︹︺︻︼︽︾︿﹀﹁﹂﹃﹄|
﹇﹈﹉﹊﹋﹌﹍﹎﹏﹐﹑﹒﹓﹔﹕﹖﹗﹘﹙﹚﹛﹜﹝﹞﹟﹠﹡﹢﹣﹤﹥﹦﹧﹨﹩﹪﹫﹬﹭﹮﹯ﹰﹱﹲﹳﹴ﹵ﹶﹷﹸﹹﹺﹻﹼﹽﹾﹿﺀﺁﺂﺃﺄﺅﺆﺇﺈﺉﺊﺋﺌﺍﺎﺏﺐﺑﺒﺓﺔﺕﺖﺗﺘﺙﺚﺛﺜﺝﺞﺟﺠﺡﺢﺣﺤﺥﺦﺧﺨﺩﺪﺫﺬﺭﺮﺯﺰﺱﺲﺳﺴﺵﺶﺷﺸﺹﺺﺻﺼﺽ...|
...|
...|
...|
...|
...|
...|
...|
...|
...|
...|
...|
...|
...|
...|
```

NOTE 2:

I tried some of them online and some worked in clang 12 (for example) but not in https://godbolt.org/z/G1ET49erx.
Apparently some version (clang 14?) implemented this https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p1949r7.html

So, it seems to be a moving target.

NOTE 3:

Later versions of clang seem to accept some math symbols, related to the warning `-Wmathematical-notation-identifier-extension`.
https://godbolt.org/z/6K7YhzEnz

So, it still seems to be the Wild West.

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: I used this tool http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/ to convert your codes to their representation in your answer if you don't mind. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know the criterion used to choose these ranges of characters?

Comment: @alfC I feel like I have seen a rationale before but I can not find it anymore. I was able to find a document that goes into the many influences and mentions some rationale but is detail-lite. I added it to my answer.