# Nordic characters in C++ variable names

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, g++, clang++

Is it somehow possible to program in C++ using characters from the Nordic alphabet in class- and variable names? (specifically: æ, ø and å).

Example:

```
auto føø = 2;
```

I am using GCC > 6, which do not seem to support it. Is there another compiler supporting these characters?

(FYI: I have [duckduckgoed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DuckDuckGo) this, but I came up empty.)

Comment: see [Using emoji as identifier names in c++ in Visual Studio or GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30130806/1708801)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55641/unicode-processing-in-c

Comment: Answer: It is possible in clang (8.0.0) but not currently in gcc (9.0.0). Found out using wandbox.org - wonderful tool.

Comment: Re *"the Nordic alphabet"*: Aren't they distinct? Or at least two sets?

Comment: [GCC caught up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30130806/using-emoji-as-identifier-names-in-c-in-visual-studio-or-gcc/64108334#64108334) with [GCC 10.1](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/) (2020-05-07).

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://www.programtopia.net/cplusplus/docs/variables):

> ### Rules for Naming A Variable
>
> 1. A variable name can't be a C++ keyword. For example, *int* can't be a
>    variable name as it is a C++ keyword.
> 2. A variable name must start with an alphabet (A-Z and a-z) or
>    underscore ( _ ) sign. For example, var, X, _name, etc. are valid
>    variable names, but 1a, $age, etc. are invalid variable names.
> 3. Variable names can have alphabet (A-Z and a-z), underscore ( _ ),
>    digits (0-9), but they can't have other symbols, such as %, &, @ , etc. For example, *a_01* and *findSum* are valid variable names, but *name&* and *calc%* are not
>    allowed in C++.

So to answer your question:

> Is it somehow possible to program in C++ using characters from the
> Nordic alphabet in class- and variable names? (specifically: æ, ø and
> å).

It's not portable, because the standard doesn't allow it; of course it's up to the individual compiler to allow it anyway. What often does work is using a macro instead, like this:

```
#define føø my_foo
```

And then later do

```
auto føø = 2;
```

Comment: Does that source apply specifically to C++ 11? At least the current draft has different rules (for example, [*all* characters are significant](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.name#1.sentence-5)).

Comment: It doesn't specify a version. I removed that significant characters part, because honestly, it surprised me, too. After searching around a bit, it seems like the real limitation actually is "at least 32 characters", but most compilers required the whole name to be significant, anyway. Thanks to you I learned why lots of old C programs had such horrible and mangled variable names - the limit was 6 significant characters back then.

Comment: The C++-standard explicitly allows certain ranges of unicode to be part of identifiers - as long as the other rules (like not starting with and underscore or number) are not broken.
Specifically the range 00F8-00FF - which is a range starting with 'ø'.