# Is there a way to make g++ compile this program with Unicode identifiers?

Tags: c++, unicode, emoji

Consider:

```
int test(int )
{
   auto  = 5;
    += ;
   return ;
}
```

Is there a way to get g++ to compile this program? I've tried `g++ -fextended-identifiers -finput-charset=utf-8 -c utf8-test.cpp` and I get back errors like this:

```
utf8-test.cpp:1:9: error: stray ‘\360’ in program
    1 | int test(int )
      |         ^
```

It works great with clang.

Note that I'm not generally endorsing the practice of using emoji in identifiers. It was just a limit case for testing purposes. Though, I have a class it would be really nice to name ℤpField (with a nice type alias to ZPField to save everyone the pain of figuring out how to type it).

**Edit:** The TLDR answer appears to be that gcc will likely support this in gcc 10, but it doesn't right now, and this is a known issue. It's also not clear that this support is required by the standard and it's possible that you're required to use `\U` escaped hexadecimal or [UCN sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C#Universal_character_names) to specify Unicode characters in identifiers.

Comment: I'm curious, what is the use case?

Comment: [This stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2681996) says that g++ can not do this.

Comment: @JohnDvorak - Edited potential use-case into the question.

Comment: Clang can do that.

Comment: It compiles with g++ https://wandbox.org/permlink/PqqOU3GarsYQ4V7B

Comment: The emojis are out of the range of identifiers that are [allowed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers), although the ℤ is in the allowed range.

Comment: Consider reading [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67224). GCC 10 will probably support this. It seems coherent with what @anastaciu said (as it uses GCC 10).

Comment: @anastaciu - Wandbox must be doing something a little strange with the preprocessor then. My version of g++ (`g++ (GCC) 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1)
`) does not do this.

Comment: Between the comments and the answers at the question pointed to, I think this question has been answered.

Comment: @Omnifarious, mine too, it's most certainly the fact that wandbox has  gcc HEAD 10.0.1 20200 version, when you compile it with 9.2.0 it also fails with consistent errors.

Comment: reminded me of Stroustrups [`my_phone->off_hook();` proposal](http://www.stroustrup.com/whitespace98.pdf)

Comment: A better duplicate may be *[ (and other Unicode characters) in identifiers not allowed by g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692067/)*.